# Does your blood stop moving in between heart beats?

Tags: hematology, cardiology, blood-circulation

Does blood stop moving in between heart beats or does it move continuously?

Comment: Welcome Akshay. This is not simply a Q&A site, here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on, see our section on [how to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and see our [homework-question policy](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Enjoy the Stackexchange network.

Comment: I couldnt find the answer fairly simply on google, so i wrote one here, so that it exists on the web. Agreed the question looks like a homework query without prior investigation.

Comment: I think there is a difference whether you mean veins or arteries, and which ones.